# Python - Plot function over a range PYPLOT

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have a function

```
def function(self, x, A, B)
   ......
```

How can I plot a continuous graph of it over a range of say x=[0,150000] (A/B are constants and can be changed on each call).

Even discrete values is fine.  However it is inefficient to make a list of all function values then plot each one?

Comment: Your question is not very clear here. Plotting is always discrete. There are just way too many numbers in a closed interval of real numbers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the function is going to be some kind of mathematical function, for example:

```
import math
def function(x, A, B):
    return math.exp(A*x) * math.sin(B*x)
```

Then I would define variables for the number of points to plot, and the x range, and then create lists using `map`, as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
points = 1e4 #Number of points
xmin, xmax = -1, 5
xlist = map(lambda x: float(xmax - xmin)*x/points, range(points+1))
ylist = map(lambda y: function(y, -1, 5), xlist)
plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am getting error- `>>> xlist = map(lambda x: float(xmax - xmin)*x/points, range(points+1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: @Ankit Make sure the variable `points` is an integer (there can only be an integer number of points). The error comes from calling `range` with a non-integer argument. This answer was written for Python 2 where `1e4` is an integer, whereas it is a float in Python 3.

Comment: Instead of `xlist = map(lambda x: float(xmax - xmin)*x/points, range(points+1))` you may wish to use NumPy's `linspace` function: `import numpy as np` and then `xlist = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, points)`